# Append function, not able to get the right result

Tags: python-2.7, append

I'm having the following problem.

```
for som in range(0,len(var)):                                         # For each number in var (the sequence)
        if len(PeriodNumbers[som]) != 2:                                  # When the length of PeriodNumbers is not 2 (2 meaning that there's a column falling in 2 different periods)
            TempColNrsperPeriod.append(var[som])                          # When the if statement is valid we append the column from the sequence.
            #print TempColNrsperPeriod
        else:                                                             # When the if statement is false ( meaning that lenght is 2):
            TempColNrsperPeriod.append(var[som])                          # We append the current column to the temp list 
            ColNrsperPeriod.append([TempColNrsperPeriod])                 # Appending the Temp list to the ColNrsperPeriod list
        # I do not set the TempcolNrsperPeriod to 0, since I want the next appending to be the cummulative of all columns up until and including the current period.

var = [42, 30, 45, 61, 62, 80, 81, 101, 83, 66, 49, 24, 15, 25, 52, 39, 53, 68, 54, 41, 29, 28, 17, 26, 51, 50, 48, 34, 64, 65, 84, 67, 35, 47, 33, 63, 82, 100, 119, 141, 140, 115, 137, 136, 113, 159, 183, 213, 185, 158, 209, 231, 208, 230, 207, 206, 154, 178, 126, 104, 105, 129, 130, 155, 179, 153, 106, 127, 177, 151, 152, 128, 107, 108, 89, 90, 91, 111, 157, 131, 156, 182, 212, 160, 134, 133, 110, 109, 132, 92, 93, 74, 72, 73, 56, 57, 58, 75, 76, 94, 112, 135, 161, 186, 162, 138, 114, 95, 97, 77, 60, 43, 44, 31, 32, 46, 78, 116, 98, 118, 120, 99, 117, 139, 163, 187, 251, 260, 252, 259, 258, 266, 253, 222, 173, 202, 172, 171, 197, 238, 237, 219, 195, 167, 217, 193, 164, 216, 235, 246, 215, 191, 192, 233, 232, 214, 165, 194, 166, 142, 168, 198, 236, 248, 250, 249, 257, 263, 247, 234, 218, 196, 169, 143, 144, 121, 148, 146, 170, 199, 223, 240, 241, 242, 201, 203, 174, 175, 204, 228, 176, 205, 245, 244, 254, 262, 261, 239, 221, 220, 79, 59, 96, 103, 124, 147, 123, 125, 150, 149, 200, 224, 225, 226, 243, 227, 255, 190, 189, 188, 86, 87, 70, 71, 88, 38, 37, 36, 23, 14, 8, 16, 9, 10, 27, 40, 69, 85, 102, 20, 19, 18, 11, 3, 6, 12, 4, 5, 13, 7, 2, 1, 55, 184, 210, 211, 181, 180, 229, 264, 265, 256, 122, 145, 22, 21]

PeriodNumbers =[[1], [1], [1, [2]], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2], [2, [3]], [3], [3], [3], [3], [3, [4]], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4, 5], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5, [6]], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6, [7]], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7, [8]], [8], [8], [8], [8], [8], [8], [8], [8], [8, [9]], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9, 10], [10], [10], [10], [10, [11]], [11], [11], [11], [11], [11], [11], [11, [12]], [12], [12], [12], [12], [12, [13]], [13], [13], [13], [13, [14]], [14], [14], [14], [14], [14], [14], [14], [14, [15]], [15], [15], [15], [15], [15, [16]], [16], [16], [16], [16, [17]], [17], [17], [17], [17], [17], [17, [18]], [18], [18], [18], [18], [18], [18], [18], [18], [18, [19]], [19], [19], [19], [19, [20]], [20], [20], [20], [20], [20], [20], [20], [20], [20], [20, [21]], [21], [21], [21], [21], [21], [21], [21], [21], [21], [21], [21, [22]], [22], [22], [22], [22], [22, [23]], [23], [23], [23], [23], [23, 24], [24], [24], [24], [24], [24], [24], [24], [24, [25]], [25], [25], [25], [25], [25], [25, [26]], [26], [26], [26], [26], [26], [26], [26], [26], [26], [26], [26, [27]], [27], [27], [27], [27], [27, 28], [28], [28], [28], [28], [28], [28, [29]], [29], [29], [29], [29], [29], [29], [29, [30]], [30], [30], [30], [30], [30], [30], [30], [30], [30, [31]], [31], [31], [31], [31], [31], [31], [31, 32], [32], [32], [32], [32], [32, [33]], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33], [33, [34]], [34], [34], [34], [34], [34], [34, [35]], [35], [35], [35], [35], [35], [35], [35, [36]], [36], [36], [36], [36], [36], [36], [36], [36], [36, [37]], [37], [37], [37], [37], [37], [37], [37], [37, [38]], [38], [38], [38], [38], [38], [38], [38], [38], [38], [38, [39]], [39], [39], [39], [39], [39], [39], [39]]
```

What I would like to achieve is (For each period from the periodnumbers, I would like to have the set of all values up until then and whitin that period. And append these outcomes to ColNrsperPeriod as I tried showing below):

```
ColNrsperPeriod = [[42, 30, 45],[42, 30, 45, 61, 62, 80, 81, 101, 83],[......
```

For some reason I can not get it to work and fail to see what is the problem.

Please let me know what I should do to fix this. Thank you so much.

Comment: `ColNrsperPeriod.append([TempColNrsperPeriod])` - `ColNrsperPeriod` would contains N copies of same list. Lists are mutable. If you want to append there current state of list, you need to create a copy. Try `ColNrsperPeriod.append(TempColNrsperPeriod[:])` .

Comment: Great, thanks.  That did indeed solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColNrsperPeriod.append([TempColNrsperPeriod]) - ColNrsperPeriod` would contains N copies of same list. Lists are mutable, so changes from next interations would propagate to previously appended list.

If you want to append there current state of list, you need to create a copy.
Try `ColNrsperPeriod.append(TempColNrsperPeriod[:])`.